# Serving Dynamic Tiles

Tags: ogr, tiles, mapnik, utfgrid

I want to display data (tiles and utfgrid info) inside MSSQL on top of google maps using Mapnik.

I have looked into mapnik and setup a small prototype both with tilestache and also with node-mapnik following http://www.nautilytics.com/blogs/2014/04/15/running-route-tile-server/ .

I prefer to use nodejs and the node-mapnik method, as I think  using nodeJS would be easiest to modify the server-side to allow for dynamic tiles.

---

I need to use the ogr virtual format to connect to MSSQL in order to get live data to create the tiles, or alternatively get data from a redis server. ( Found NO information about using mapnik and a redis datasource). Connecting to MSSQL is something currently broken in Mapnik, but should be fixed soon:

I am having issues finding a solution that allows for serving different tiles based on a session/SQL query similar to the idea mentioned : http://forumone.com/insights/mapping-county-health-rankings-mapnik-nodejs-and-postgresql/

I have an idea how I can take additional GET parameters in the tileserver such as `/{z}/{y}/{z}/png?sql=SELECT id,lng,lat,type FROM LOCATIONS` then parse it with nodeJS to extract the live data and serve the points using Mapnik.

I know I can define a datasource on the fly using nodeJS using postgres but not sure if this can be done with OGR. 
My hope is that using the Mapnik OGR virtual layer that the query is processed only once, and not every tile request.

I also have absolutely no idea how to get the data to display on the map. I know a good technique is using UTFGrids but I havent been able to find out to translate data inside a database to usable UTFGrids, only tutorials on how to do it using non-dynamic data using TileMill.

So I need help on how to create session-based tiles and how to generate UTFGrids from a database using Mapnik